# Unexpected while behavior C++ (perhaps IDE related)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, while-loop, visual-studio-2015

I am writing a very simple program to count and display the number of consecutive integers in an inputted sequence (an exercise to teach myself about while loops and conditionals). The code is as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h" //obviously using VS
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int currVal = 0, val = 0;
    if (std::cin >> currVal) {
        int cnt = 1; //number of consecutive values
        while (std::cin >> val) {
            if (val == currVal)
                ++cnt;
            else {
                std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
                currVal = val;
                cnt = 1;
            }
        }
        std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the last cout line, I account for the eof behavior that should exit the while loops without printing the last value. However, in VS 2015 the last line is not being printed and the while loop is apparently not terminating despite cnt no longer incrementing. The console continues running and accepts further inputs, and will actually return that last value if I enter another value or a non-integer. The final console looks like this:

[image: Console]

And with another input:

[image: Console 2]

Yet when I run the same code in an online compiler like Ideone, the result is correct and the loop terminates. http://ideone.com/mUZuh7

[image: Ideone]

Is this some unusual behavior of Visual Studio, or is there some obvious beginners mistake in my code that I'm overlooking.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a mistake in your code, and as [TeamEnternode points out in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33115361/4143855) it's unusual behaviour for [Ideone](https://ideone.com/).

Your `while` loop continue to process while there is a character to read from `std::cin`; however, after it reads the last `4`, it increments `cnt` and doensn't output anything (as per your `if` statement). When the `while` loop next evaluates `std::cin`, there's nothing in it anymore!

Your code works as you probably expect if you don't end your input with a double (e.g. `1 2 3 4 4 5` ).

Here's what your code is doing (assume input is `1 2 3 4 4`):

1. `if (std::cin >> currVal)`: waits for input from `std::cin`. You will need to enter something in the console and press enter to get past this.
2. `currVal` is equal to `1`, and the first letter from your input.
3. `while (std::cin >> val)` read another character from `std::cin`. This will read `2`: `val` is now `2`.
4. `if (val == currVal)`: `1` is not equal to `2`, so your code outputs the occurrences of `1`, and changes `currVal` to `2`.
5. `while (std::cin >> val)` read another character from `std::cin`. This will read `3`: `val` is now `3`.
6. `if (val == currVal)`: `2` is not equal to `3`, so your code outputs the occurrences of `2`, and changes `currVal` to `3`.
7. `while (std::cin >> val)` read another character from `std::cin`. This will read `4`: `val` is now `4`.
8. `if (val == currVal)`: `3` is not equal to `4`, so your code outputs the occurrences of `3`, and changes `currVal` to `4`.
9. `while (std::cin >> val)` read another character from `std::cin`. This will read another `4`, and `val` will remain as `4`.
10. `if (val == currVal)`: `4` *is* equal to `4`, so `cnt` is incremented
11. `while (std::cin >> val)` there is nothing further to read from `std::cin`.

If you input another different character (e.g. `5`), the `while` loop will continue, evaluate that `5 != 4` and then output `4`s occurrences and set `currVal` to `5`. It will then try your `while` loop again; however, the input is once again empty.

Visual Studio is running the code correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I apologize if this is an ignorant question, but I am still somewhat confused about the std::cin input and the eol behavior. I had assumed when writing this code that the while loop would terminate when there was nothing further to read from cin because an attempt to retrieve or store the input would be invalid/false. How does this work? Why can I continue to input after the code has been run? Thanks!

Comment: `std::cin` blocks the `while` loop, so once the end of line has been reached (the final `4`) the `while` loop checks if there's anything else there and `std::cin` WAITS for there to be something there. If you wrote a program that simply `int main() { int n; std::cin >> n; return 0; }` the program would not exit until input had been entered. Similarly, `while(std::cin >> n) {}` wouldn't exit. You may wish to only read input once (i.e. **not** in the `while` loop) and then process each character in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's unusual behavior in the online compiler.

I'm assuming that the online compiler's standard input will only read until the end of the line, while a normal C++ program will read until end-of-file (either invalid output or the end-of-file shortcut is used), Because the while loop's condition at the end of 
1 2 3 4 4
is not false. To fix your problem, you would have to read one line at a time (which you are yet to learn how to do I'm assuming), or wait to output anything at all and just save the information to a container and output everything at the end (which you are also yet to learn to do).

I can't really give you a fix in a way that you would understand. Just ignore the bug for now, and once you know more about how Standard I/O works, you can fix the bug then.

Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this. Could I somehow add an 'if (eof()) {break}' statement in the while loop to simulate that behavior?

Comment: Or thinking about it some more an if cin.empty() or if (cin>>)var = NULL or 0 conditional.